# In python, after reading the txt text, how to delete the words that exist in another txt file

Tags: python

After reading the `policy_new` file, I need to count the frequency of each word. I first delete the punctuation in the text, and then I need to delete the stop words in the text, such as "the". All the stop words that need to be deleted are stored in another txt file. I read them and store them in the list. I can't delete these words when I use replace function。How can I do it？

Like so

```
import re
with open('../data/policy_new.txt','r') as handle:
  line = handle.read()
  newline = re.sub("[\!\"\#\$\%\&\\\'\(\)\*\+\,\-\.\/\:\;\<\=\>\?\@\[\\\\\]\^\_\`\{\|\}\~\“\”\‘\’]+", "",line)
with open('../data/stop_words.txt','r') as handle2:
  stopwords=handle2.readlines()
  for i in range(len(stopwords)):
    stopwords[i] = stopwords[i].strip()
    policy = newline.replace(stopwords[i],'')
```

Comment: Please post code as text, not as an image.

Comment: You need to open the file where you want to write in write mode (w) or read and write (rw), not just read mode (r).

Comment: Do you mean delete _from the file,_ or from the string in memory? In the latter case, how does your current code fail?

Comment: What I mean is to delete words from the policy file, and the words that need to be deleted are stored in another stop words file. @tripleee

Comment: I just need to delete words from this file. Does this also need to use write?@DevelJoe

Comment: [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/automate-boring-tasks-with-your-own-functions-a32785437179) Give this a read.

Comment: I tried to delete words from the string, the code did not report an error, but it was not deleted successfully.@tripleee

Comment: The words are in memory, you have to write them back to the file if that's what you want.

Comment: The content in the string is not what I want, my problem is how to delete the stop words？@tripleee